# How to order dynamic frame data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

this code used in aws glue job:

```
def get_latest_records(data_frame, record_keys, key):
    columns = data_frame.columns

    window_spec = w.partitionBy(*record_keys).orderBy(f.desc(key))

    output_data_frame = data_frame.withColumn("row_num", f.row_number().over(window_spec)). \
        filter(f.col("row_num") == 1). \
        drop(f.col("row_num")). \
        select(columns)

    return data_frame
```

I want to order the dynamic frame data according a column called "name" then if two names are equal, order by the "key" column.
How to do this?
Also, can you explain what (drop) does in the output_data_frame?

Comment: Where does the `f` come from here? Is that an AWS Glue primitive available to the Glue script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the value for `record_keys` is an iterable with the single value `"name"` this should already do it.

You should call the function like this:

```py
output_df = get_latest_records(
    data_frame=input_df,  # The name of the dataframe you want to process
    record_keys=["name"],
    key="key",
)
```

**What's going on?**

The code partitions the data by the "name" column that way and within each partition sorts it in descending order by "key". Within each partition it also adds a new column `row_num` using the `row_number()` function that sequentially adds the row number to each row in the partition.

By filtering on `row_num` with the value 1 you get the first row from the partition which is the datapoint you're looking for. Then the artificial column `row_num` is dropped again because you don't need it on the outside and you return all the columns from the original dataframe.

Comment: But I want it to be ordered by name desc, not just partition, for example: Maurice first, then Bob, then Ali.... should this code work?

Comment: At the point where it's sorted, all values have the same name - that's what the window function does - it partitions by the name and within the partition the sorting happens.

Comment: Is it okay to have two record_keys? I have already "id". Adding "name" caused a problem

Comment: If you add it as a list it should be fine.